# using handler for every single task(method) in android

Tags: android, multithreading

Hello i am new to android and android thread so want to know that

How could we use more number of thread in order to perform every single task or method so that while user click on any UI component it does effect the performance ,having little knowledge of how the handler `thread` and `asynctask` work.But how can we run every method inside the `asynctask` so to do the operation and mean while user can do the other operation also.

In the application

- i have voice recording from mic.
- next showing progress bar.
- next showing gallery with some image and with that setting effect to the picture.

Comment: What do you want to do? What's the question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300574/handlers-vs-asynchronous-calls-in-android  try reading link

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)s for long running tasks. So, not everything needs to be run with AsyncTasks, as you can get a performance hit due to the context switching.

As for how AsyncTasks work, read the documentation.

Comment: You should make a decision of what tasks are time consuming/ time sensitive and then run those in AsyncTasks. Also keep in mind, that UI can only update from the UI thread, hence you should use Handler to update any UI (e.g. Progress Bar or Gallary update).

Comment: so the better way will aynctask or handler because asynctask can update UI after completing operation

Answer (score 0):

Use an `AsyncTask` and make sure to implement these as needed. You mention the idea of doing something in the background while a user is doing something so I'm guessing you'll want to alter the UI.

Take a look at these links for an more details from Android. They cover `Runnable`, `AsyncTask` and `Handler`

- Overview of them all http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html
- AsyncTask example http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
- Old but relevant, *Painless Threading* http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html
- Another, more complex example http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

I don't generally paste full examples in here but I had a lot of trouble finding an example I was happy with for a long time and to help you and others, here is my preferred method. I generally use an `AsyncTask` with a callback to the `Activity` that started the task.

In this example, I'm pretending that a user has triggered `onClick(...)` such as with a button, but could be anything that triggers a call into the `Activity`.

```
// Within your Activity, call a custom AsyncTask such as MyTask
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, MyTask.OnTaskComplete {
    //...

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // For example, thet user clicked a button
        // get data via your task

        // using `this` will tell the MyTask object to use this Activty
        // for the listener
        MyTask task = new MyTask(this);
        task.execute(); // data returned in callback below
    }

    public void onTaskComplete(MyObject obj) {
        // After the AsyncTask completes, it calls this callback.
        // use your data here
        mTextBox.setText(obj.getName);
    }
}
```

Getting the data out of a task can be done many ways, but I prefer an interface such as `OnTaskComplete` that is implemented above and triggered below.

The main idea here is that I often want to keep away from inner classes as they become more complex. Mostly a personal preference, but it allows me to separate reusable tasks outside of one class.

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, MyObject> {

    public static interface OnTaskComplete {
        public abstract void onTaskComplete(MyObject obj);
    }
    static final String TAG = "MyTask";

    private OnTaskComplete mListener;

    public MyTask(OnTaskComplete listener) {
        Log.d(TAG, "new MyTask");
        if (listener == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("Listener may not be null");

        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected MyObject doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground");
        // do background tasks

        MyObbject obj = new MyObject();
        // Do long running tasks here to not block the UI
        obj.populateData();
        return 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(MyObject obj) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute");
        this.mListener.onTaskComplete(obj);
    }
}
```